# Displaying a message when a certain array element is present in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

This program displays certain messages when some of the elements are `'y'` or if all of the elements are `'n'`.

My question is about this line: `someElements |= array[i] == 'y'`.
I understand that it can be written in this way: `someElements = someElements | array[i] == 'y'`.

I'm just asking for an explanation why does it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    char array[3] = { 0 };

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        do {
        printf("\nElement No.%d [y/n]: ", i + 1);
        scanf(" %c", &array[i]);
            if (array[i] != 'y' && array[i] != 'n') {
            printf("Must be a lowercase 'y' or 'n'\n");
            } 
        } while (array[i] != 'y' && array[i] != 'n');
    }

    int someElements = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        someElements |= array[i] == 'y';
    }
    if (someElements) {
        printf("\nSOME of the elements = y.\n");
    }
    else{
         printf("\nNONE of the elements = y.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Code link](https://onlinegdb.com/8EUCcEMP9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `array[i] == 'y'` is a boolean true or false. It can be implicitly converted to the `int` value `1` or `0` (respectively).

Then it's easy to create a bitwise OR table for the possible combinations of `someElements | array[i] == 'y'`:

| `someElements` | `array[i] == 'y'` | `someElements | array[i] == 'y'` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `0` | `0` |
| `0` | `1` | `1` |
| `1` | `0` | `1` |
| `1` | `1` | `1` |

So if any of the values are `1` then the result will be `1`.

From this follows that if any of the characters in the array is equal to `'y'` then the end result of `someElements` after the loop will be `1`. Which then can be implicitly converted back to a boolean true in the following `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

The key insight is for a given binary value `x`:

1. `0 | x == x`
2. `1 | x == 1`

We initialize the variable `someElemenets` to 0 (false) so we are in the first case. `someElemenets` will remain 0 till we encounter an 'y' in the array.  It now becomes 1 and will remain so irregardless of the remaining input.  Think of it as a one-way (light) switch.

You could just terminate the loop early instead:

```
 someElements = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < 3 && !someElements; i++) {
        someElements = array[i] == 'y';
 }
```

and it even clearer if you write it as a function:

```
int any_y(size_t n, const char array[n]) {
   for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if(array[i] == 'y') return 1
   return 0
}
```

which is specialization of `memchr()`:

```
someElements = memchr(array, 'y', 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bitwise OR**:

Returns true if either bit is true.

Truth table:

```
A | B | A | B
-------------
0 | 0 | 0
1 | 0 | 1
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 1 | 1
```

From this, we can conclude that

```
someElements = someElements | array[i] == 'y;
```

as `someElements` has been initialized with 0, or `false`, it will remain `false` until `array[i] = 'y'` returns 1, or `true`.

---

**Aside:** On the last iteration, `i + 1` would access out of bounds memory.